# problem with actionfunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, ajax, actionfunction

I have a page with actionFunction to get a parameter onclick on an outputLink from 3 defined.

but this warning appear after loading the page before I click on anything..

```
hitMe=function(one){A4J.AJAX.Submit('AccPage:warningf',null,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){poporder()},'similarityGroupingId':'AccPage:warningf:j_id2','parameters':{'AccPage:warningf:j_id2':'AccPage:warningf:j_id2','one':(typeof one!='undefined'&&one!=null)?one:''} } )};
```

the AccPage is the id of

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="hitMe('first'); return false; " >first</apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputLink onclick="hitMe('second'); return false;" >second</apex:outputLink>
<apex:outputLink onclick="hitMe('third'); return false;" >third</apex:outputLink>
```

and the action function code is

```
<apex:actionFunction
                    name="hitMe"
                    action="{!testfn}"
                    oncomplete="poporder()" // javaScript function display popup div
                    reRender="ordersPage">
     <apex:param name="one" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

and the testfn in Controller like this

```
public PageReference testfn(){
        selectedAccount = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('one');

        getAccountInfo();
        getSomething();
        return null;
    }
```

and the poporder javascript function

```
<script>
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j(document).ready(function(){

      });

      function poporder(){
        $j("#pop-order").toggle();
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say a warning appears, is that message appearing in an alert?  It looks highly like debugging information to me - perhaps in an onload handler.

You'd get that type of output if you had a line of JavaScript such as:

alert('hitMe=' + hitMe);

as this would display the details of the hitMe function.

I'd check the rest of your page and any included components/static resources to see if there is a debugging alert of this type.

Comment: no without alert or debugging, it's appears where i write the actionFunction on the page..

Comment: So the actionfunction source appears on the page when it is rendered by the browser? Or in the page source?

Comment: when it is rendered .. when i inspect element it appears like this .. `<script id="AccPage:warningf:j_id2" type="text/javascript">hitMe=function(one){A4J.AJAX.Submit ...
</script>`

Comment: That is what the actionfunction is supposed to render - it creates a JavaScript function based on the markup that does an AJAX submission.  If this is appearing on the page when it is rendered can you post a screenshot and your full page code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your trying to help Mr. @Bob Buzzard , I feel like I'm stupid ! the page with id AccPage has style with `display:inline-block`. and the script tag by default `display:none`. which deprecated. all what I do is giving script tag style `display:none !importantl;`